# HTML hyperlinked images moving etc

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

[This is the site I'm working on](http://www.saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php) and the CSS is in the same directory called saucy.css (sorry I can only post one hyperlink).

First of all, apologies for my awfully invalid HTML and CSS. I promise I'm going to fix it all once the site is up and running! However if this is causing the problems of course I will do it now.

My current problems:

- When I add a hyperlink to the Twitter
  icon it moves to the top left as it
  is now. As you can see from the HTML
  it should be under the main box (in
  line with the copyright logo etc.) to
  the left.
- I have this strange text appearing
  at the bottom of my page: â€‹. I am told it is to do with not being able to display a character properly, but I can't see what character it could be.
- When I try and    edit the CSS to
  remove the link    formatting on the
  navbar, nothing    happens.
- I am unable to add a border to the
  box in the centre of the page. As the
  drop downs are part of the table, I
  only want a border for the  or
   which is grey. Is it possible to
  do this?

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: "if this is causing the problems of course I will do it now" — fix it now and see if that resolves the issue before you ask other people to debug code that you know if broken.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it looks like you rushed to put this together... You really should take your time with it so you don't make mistakes. I see that you've inverted a TD tag where there should be a TR tag. I also see that you've closed a TR tag and decided to just use a TD tag instead, which i'm not sure if that's intentional or not lol. I'm going to comment on some of your code and ask you if it was intentional or not, but I will clean it up a bit first.

You should never just run all your code together, that's very bad practice and will cause you to forget to close tags. Always indent when you can. Whether you can write colspan=4 or not is irrelevant, you should always put it in quotes like this: colspan="4" and for all other properties.

For the level you're at, you should be using xhtml. This will force the browsers to use the standardizations and prevent your site from looking "weird" on one browser but perfect on another.

Here is your code that I commented on. You really need to go through it and match ALL of your opening/closing tags correctly. You've made a nice mess for yourself lol. Have fun.

```
<table align="center" width="60%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"> 
 <tr>
  <td colspan=4>
   <div class="logo">saucydares</div> 
   <div class="slogan">fun and games for couples everywhere!</div>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="links"> 
  <td class="links" colspan=4 width="100%" align=center><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a> | <a href="#">ARCHIVE</a> | <a href="#">DARE BOX</a></td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td colspan=4 class="main" cellpadding=10> 
   <br><br> <!-- Breaks should always be <br /> XHTML only //-->


    <table height="270px" width="450px" align=center cellpadding="5"> 
        <tr class="box">
         <td align=center>
          <div id="dare">Welcome to Saucy Dares! To get going, adjust the settings below and click "Dare me!".</div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- There is no TR tag here. 
             Was it on purpose? //-->
        <td height="20px" align=right cellpadding="0">
            <form name="form"> 

            <select id="mode" name="mode"> 
            <option value="classic">Classic Collection</option> 
            <option value="long">The Long Game</option> 
            </select> 

            <select name="player"> 
            <option value="him">For him</option> 
            <option value="her">For her</option> 
            <option value="double">Double dare</option> 
            </select> 

            <input type="button" value="Dare me!" onClick="get();"> 
            </form> 
         </tr> <!-- You closed the parent TR before the child TD //-->
        </td>  <!-- This TD no longer applies to anything because you
                    closed its parent row //-->
    </table> 


<br><br> <!-- Breaks should always be <br /> XHTML only //-->
<b>Latest news</b> 
<UL> 
<LI> Welcome to the new look Saucy Dares! Now you can take things to the next level with the new game mode, The Long Game. You can also both get involved by selecting 'Double dare' from the second drop down box. Read more about the new game modes on the <a href="/about.html">About page</a>.
<LI>Dares now appear without needing to refresh the page meaning your settings aren't reset every time you view a new dare.
<LI> What do you like about the new design? What is still missing? Let us know on Twitter! You can also follow @SaucyDares to receive updates whenever new features and dares are added.
<LI> You can now share your favourite dares with us by putting them in the <a href="/darebox.html">Dare Box</a>!
</UL> 
 </tr> <!-- Because you already closed the TR in your
            child table, this is going to cause some
            weird effects lol //-->
</td> <!-- More weird effects are going to occur until
           you match the correct closing tags to
           their opening tags //-->

<tr class="footer"><img src="facebook_border.gif">&nbsp;

<a href="http://www.twitter.com/saucydares" target="_blank"><img src="twitter_border.gif" alt="Twitter" border="0"></a> 

</td><td width="33%" align=center>&copy; 2010 Saucy Dares</td><td width="33%" align=right>Click <a href="mailto:saucydares@yahoo.com">here</a> to report an error</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same code you used for your site but, I removed all the table elements to help you out and got it looking somewhat nice please check it out and let me know what you think or if you need anything else. I might have made some minor mistakes or not up to website standards but, this was done on the fly.

```
   <h3 class="logo" style="text-align:center; weight:bold;">saucydares</h3> <!--center these in your css file. or inline style it like I did. -->
   <h3 class="slogan" style="text-align:center;">fun and games for couples everywhere!</h3><!--center these in your css file. or inline style it like I did. -->

 <div class="links" style="text-align:center;"> 
    <br /><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a> | <a href="#">ARCHIVE</a> | <a href="#">DARE BOX</a><br /> <br />
   </div>

<h5 id="dare" style="text-align:center;">Welcome to Saucy Dares! To get going, adjust the settings below and click "Dare me!".</h5><br />

            <form name="form" style="text-align:center;"> 

            <select id="mode" name="mode"> 
            <option value="classic">Classic Collection</option> 
            <option value="long">The Long Game</option> 
            </select><br />

            <select name="player"> 
            <option value="him">For him</option> 
            <option value="her">For her</option> 
            <option value="double">Double dare</option> 
            </select> 
            <br />

            <input type="button" value="Dare me!" onClick="get();"> 
            </form> 


<br /><br /> <!-- Breaks should always be <br />-->
<b>Latest news</b> 
<UL> 
<LI> Welcome to the new look Saucy Dares! Now you can take things to the next level with the new game mode, The Long Game. You can also both get involved by selecting 'Double dare' from the second drop down box. Read more about the new game modes on the <a href="/about.html">About page</a>.
<LI>Dares now appear without needing to refresh the page meaning your settings aren't reset every time you view a new dare.
<LI> What do you like about the new design? What is still missing? Let us know on Twitter! You can also follow @SaucyDares to receive updates whenever new features and dares are added.
<LI> You can now share your favourite dares with us by putting them in the <a href="/darebox.html">Dare Box</a>!
</UL> 

<div style="text-align:center;" class="footer"><img src="facebook_border.gif"><br />

<a style="text-align:center;" href="http://www.twitter.com/saucydares" target="_blank"><img style="text-align:center;" src="twitter_border.gif" alt="Twitter" border="0" /></a> 

<h3 width="33%" style="text-align:center;">&copy; 2010 Saucy Dares</h3><p width="33%" style="text-align:center;">Click <a style="text-align:center;" href="mailto:saucydares@yahoo.com">here</a> to report an error</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Remember make sure your css is correct and look out for the inline styles I made in your elements so it doesn't make things look out of place. Also your site wasn't up so I couldn't really see it.  Best of luck on your development adventure @Sebastian.     ALSO please remember for next time and even now if you want always always share code so we can see what is going on yes a URL is fine but, I myself and I can probably speak for a lot of individuals at SO we like to see code. Also not to sound mean cause I helped you out a lot, if you know something is wrong please try and fix it first. TY.

Comment: I also fixed the tweet tweet problem with it going to the top left of page it is now centered down in the footer area. Also for the link issue and css not working try adding inline style with the <a> element's or use <a> element tag in your css.  Also, removed the strange text that was bothering you and one last thing I didn't add a box around the text cause I forgot that problem but, I believe now you can add one. Also I think for the most part building the site with tables like that one must remember how tables format and display on screen not saying this is what you thought but, some do.